# How i can create a very big stream for imititate big file?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, testing

I am working on a multi-threaded archiver and at the moment I am thinking about how I can create a unit test that will send a very large stream to the class, instead of keeping the test files for compression.
Is it possible?
That my program.cs

```
 using (var sourceStream = new FileStream(args[1], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                using (var destinationStream = new FileStream(args[2], FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    AbstractArchiver archiver;
                    switch (args[0])
                    {
                        case "compress":
                            archiver = new Compress(sourceStream, destinationStream);
                            archiver.Run();
                            break;
                        case "decompress":
                            archiver = new Decompress(sourceStream, destinationStream);
                            archiver.Run();
                            break;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Write a custom `Stream` class that generates data dynamically instead of using a physical file.

Comment: Wow, that is a nice idea but can you show me more about that? I mean, sorry I'm less experience developer and don't imagine how I can do that.

Comment: Another option could be creating MemoryStream as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623045/create-a-stream-without-having-a-physical-file-to-create-from).

Comment: ^ you are right